# Handle form post event via jquery for a validated form (unobtrusive validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have to handle the submit event of a form and possibly block the post. ex:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (){
  if (someCondition)
    return true //post;
  else
    return false //dont post
});
```

That part works, but now I have jquery.validate plugin with jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

I want this part of code to run *after* validation is passed (and only if the form is valid).

Any ideas?

### Some clarifications

The validation plugin is the jquery.validate plugin from [bassistance](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
I use Microsofts' [unobtrusive](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js) (wich is shipped along with MVC3) plugin on top of it.
I think it's in the `validationInfo` function in jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js that the job must be done...

Comment: Don't shoot me if I am mistaken, but don't you have to submit your form before you can validate it? EDIT: Tried stacking your functions within each other?

Comment: When the user click submit, the validation plugin do his job and possibly prevent the submit if the form is not valid. Basically a want to do some business when the form is valid, before it is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Rory, I achieved what I wanted.
Since jquery.validator.unobtrusive handles the call to jquery.validate, and does not provide a way to intercept anything (yep, that's an Microsoft plugin...), the solution is to use the `submitHandler` option like Rory suggested, but throught the `setDefault` method:

```
   if (typeof ($.validator) != 'undefined') {
      $.validator.setDefaults({
         submitHandler: function (form) {
            if (someCondition)
               return true; //post
            else
               return false; //dont post
         }

      });
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        if (someCondition)
            return true; //post
        else
            return false; //dont post
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it's a good start, but there is jquery.validate.unobtrusive who is calling `.validate` on the form. I'm checking if I can give the submit handler to the unobtrusive plugin.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread your OP and thought you were using the Bassistance validate plugin.

Comment: Yes, this is Bassistance validate plugin, with jquery.validate.unobstrive on top of it. The unobtrusive plugin is shipped with Microsoft's MVC. I'll clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but have a look at the `submitHandler` option in the jQueryValidate plugin:

> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate